# How to use JQuery ajaxForm with nicEdit?

Tags: jquery, serialization, alter

I am using ajaxForm function to submit my form that has nicEdit html editor as well but when I tried to submit the form for the first time the content of the nicEdit is not included... Is there a way that I can intercept the data submitted so I can edit the form data? or maybe add values to the form-data before it actually gets submitted? something like...

var options = {
   type: 'blahblah',
   success: blahblah,
   beforeSerialize: alterData
}
$('bla').ajaxForm(options)

function alterData(formdata){
   // like adding a data here
  formdata['newdata'] = im a new data!
  // then return the new form data for submit
 return formdata;
}

is there something similar to this? Appreciate all the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out just an hour ago after posting this, so if anyone has the same problem here is the solution:

there really is a beforeSerialize option!

```
...
beforeSerialize: alterData
...

function alterData(formData,options){
  var nicEdit_content = nicEditors.findEditor('id_of_textarea').getContent();
   formData.each(function(){
        $(this).find('#gth_text').val(nicEdit_content);
    })
  return true; // Return true to go back to  normal processing!
}
```

it works for me! You can probably do the same with other online html editors such as fckeditor,tinymce blah blah..

Answer (score 0):

you can use this...
I've already tried and it works.. :)

for example for file upload, i replace addForm function...

```
 nicURI : 'upload-foto.php', <!-- for upload, just echo for response file path -->

 addForm : function() {

 var formHTML = '<div id="pageForm"><form method="post" action="'+this.uri+'"><div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 5px;">Insert an Image</div><input id="upload_foto" name="upload_foto" type="file" style="margin-top: 10px;" /></form></div><div id="pageLoad" style="display: none;"><img src="http://files.nicedit.com/ajax-loader.gif" style="float: right; margin-right: 40px;" /><strong>Uploading...</strong><br />Please wait</div>';

 var goo = this;
 this.ne.selectedInstance.restoreRng();

 $(function() { 

   $(this).find('#forUpload').append(formHTML);

   $(this).find('#forUpload').find('#upload_foto').change(function(data) { 

     var thiP = $(this);
     $(this).parents('#forUpload').find('#pageForm').hide();
     $(this).parents('#forUpload').find('#pageLoad').show();

     $(this).parents('form').ajaxForm(function(data) { 

        thiP.parents('#forUpload').find('#pageForm').show();
        thiP.parents('#forUpload').find('#pageLoad').hide();
        var tmp = data;
        goo.ne.nicCommand("insertImage",tmp);
        goo.im = goo.findElm('IMG','src',tmp);

     }).submit();


   });
 });

 },
```